# What kind of diagram for Javascript constructors and prototypes ?

Tags: javascript, arrays, uml, diagram

In javascript, I have a big data structure of objects containing array of objects an so on... What kind of diagram should I use for represent them ? Especially, I want to show the relation between an array inside an object and the constructor of the objects it contains.

```
var Bar = function ()  {
    this.a;
    this.b;
}

var Foo = function () {
    this.a;
    this.b;
    this.c = []; // Array of Bar
}
```

Comment: your question is pretty vague, can you ask a more specific question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To represent the structure of objects in UML, you can use:

- an [object diagram](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-object-diagram/) to represent a snapshot of some concrete objects and their relationships at a specific moment in time; or
- a [class diagram](https://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/classdiagram.htm), to represent some general structural features shared by a families of objects, called classes.

The latter seems to make more sense here, and there are several ways to represent your case.

First, if you want to focus on `Foo` only, leaving the details of `Bar` for another diagram,  you could just show a property of type `Bar` with a multiplicity between brackets (`*` stands for unbounded, i.e. 0 to infinity in size):

[image: class Foo with properties]

But if you want to show both classes, you could go for:

[image: class Bar and Foo with simple one-to-many association]

Now the problem with this is that it shows the association between Foo and Bar,  but it doesn't show that Foo knows its Bars but Bar doesn't know anything about the Foo it belongs to.

The perfect notation for your array would be the [dot notation](https://www.omg.org/ocup-2/documents/getting_it_right_on_the_dot.pdf), putting a little dot on the Bar side.  But this notation is unfortunately not well known, and many free and entry-level tools don't support it.

An alternative is to use the [navigability notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43012322/3723423), using an arrow to show the direction of the link (and if needed a X on the other side to explicitly state the absence of navigation in the opposite direction, alas most modellers don't know about the meaning of this cross):
[image: class Bar and Foo with navigable one-to-many association]

***P.S:** As the UML guru [qwerty_so](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3379653/qwerty-so) noted in the comment of the other answer,  the shared aggregation does not add any useful information compared to a simple association and should be avoided whenever possible.  Moreover, the white diamond is not sufficient to indicate that there are many Foos for one Bar, because the same notation could be used for an and b as well.  **Multiplicity [SHOULD](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119) be explicitly indicated for an array**.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *line with a diamond at the end* instead of an arrow, which means sth like

*is part of a property of*

```
Bar -----<> Foo
```

( officially this is called *aggregation* , you can find it on [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#relationships) )

Comment: Actually the hollow diamond (shared aggregation) has no common defined semantics. Recommending it does not make any sense.

Comment: @thomas killian well it makes sense in relationship with *c - Bar[] *

Comment: So why does anything make sense that has no semantics? Only in Dada.

Comment: @thomas kilian whats your point? If youve got a better answer, add your own.. :/

Comment: His question is "what kind of diagram to use" and it's pretty pointless to answer "a class diagram".

Comment: If you'd just recommended to show a multiplicity `0..*` without that dreaded diamond I'd up-voted your answer rather than down.

Comment: It's an interesting suggestion.  But, it's still needed to disambiguate to clarify that there can be many Bars.  Indeed, many modellers use the white diamond also for single properties having no array (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/34120652/3723423 or even poplar sites such as https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy ), without prejudice of  @qwerty_so valid remark about the absence of additional semantics of shared aggregation compared to simple association (at least since UML 2 more than 20 years ago)

Comment: @Christophe You can use that thingy for anything, but it will need an wxplanation somwhere along its use. Whitout it's just some scribble. Too bad only a few people are aware of that :-(

Comment: @qwerty_so this is inertia: in the 90s it was in the original specs, and UML predecessors had it already in the 80s, because of this part-whole thing. And there is sufficiently litterature mentionning it, that you'll always find someone who has read something that it's special... ;-)

Comment: @Christophe Repeating myself: The current UML version in 2.5.1. Any older specs are **obsolete** whifh mskes them invalid. You can not argue with those.

Comment: @qwerty_so sure, as obsolete as the specifications of Roman Empire's road construction, which nevertheless made their way into the specs of the space shuttle 2000 years later [full story](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/4-feet-85-inches-space-shuttle-horses-ass-william-batch-batchelder).  I'm not defending this position, I only explain why so many people continue to use it, even though it's obsolete. For UML 2, only 20 years have passed :-)

Comment: Well, each new spec took over the old values. So they are still valid. Here this is **not** the case!